# Modal view doesn't cover whole screen

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have an app that I need to display a pin code screen every time the app is opened.  I'm successfully displaying the modal view, but it doesn't cover the navigation bar at the top, and it doesn't cover the tab bar at the bottom.  I believe it's because of how I'm presenting it, but I'm not seeing a way to change it.

This is how I'm presenting the controller

```
let newVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginView")
let view = window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
view.selectedViewController?.show(newVC, sender: nil)
```

This is the storyboard to give you an idea of the app.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your use of `UIViewController's` api, [show](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621377-show). The function is overridden by `UINavigationController` in this case and `push` will be used to present the view controller. If your plan is to modally present a view controller, rather use `present`

```
selectedViewController?.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you, I haven't had to update our app for two years, so I'm having to get up to speed with all the changes since then rebuilding it.